# Getting the parameterised type of a generic in swift?

Tags: swift, generics

How can I get the parameterised type of a generic in swift? For example to check the sizeof the type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose, for example, when you have `Array<Int>` value, what you want is `Int` type.

I believe there is no generic way to do that.

Some type has `typealias`ed the generic parameter, you can get it with that name. For example:

```
let array: Array<UInt16> = [1,2,3]
let elementType = array.dynamicType.Element.self // -> Swift.UInt16
sizeof(elementType) // -> 2
```

This works because `Array` typealiased `Element = T`:

```
struct Array<T> : MutableCollectionType, Sliceable, _DestructorSafeContainer {

    /// The type of element stored by this `Array`
    typealias Element = T
```

Even if it does not have the `typealias`, you can add it by `extension`:

```
extension Unmanaged {
    typealias Payload = T
}

let something: Unmanaged<NSString> = .passRetained("test")
something.dynamicType.Payload.self // -> NSString
```

Comment: That's indeed what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
func foo<T>(arg : T) {
    println(sizeof(T))
    // Or: println(sizeofValue(arg))
}

foo(1.2)       // 8
foo(Int8(1))   // 1
```

Comment: No, I'm looking for a function (or some other mechanism) which accepts an existing generic instance as input, and returns the instance's parameterised type/s.

Comment: @Danra: Perhaps you can add some code or pseudo-code to you question which demonstrates what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not entirely clear what you mean, but `sizeof` will work with the placeholder:

```
func f<T>(t: T) -> Int {
    return sizeof(T)
}

f(1)         // returns 1, the sizeof Int
f("hello")   // returns 24, the sizeof String
```

Bear in mind, within a generic function/type, the placeholder *is* the type.  Think of the compiler as going through and plugging the name of the actual type in wherever the placeholder appears.