# Check if variable is an Optional, and what type it wraps

Tags: swift

Is it possible to check if a variable is an optional, and what type is it wrapping?

It is possible to check if a variable is an specific optional:

```
let someString: String? = "oneString"
var anyThing: Any = someString

anyThing.dynamicType // Swift.Optional<Swift.String>
anyThing.dynamicType is Optional<String>.Type // true
anyThing.dynamicType is Optional<UIView>.Type // false
```

But is it possible to check agains any type of optional? Something like:

```
anyThing.dynamicType is Optional.Type // fails since T cant be inferred
// or 
anyThing.dynamicType is Optional<Any>.Type // false
```

And once knowing you have an optional, retrieve the type it is wrapping:

```
// hypothetical code 
anyThing.optionalType // returns String.Type
```

Comment: Anyway, you should not put `Optional` into `Any`. see: [How to unwrap an optional value from Any type?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27989094/3804019)

Comment: It may be a valid case, you could have a function that accepts `Any` and that behaves differently if it receives an `Optional`.

Answer (score 9):

Since [a protocol can be created as means of a *typeless* Optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536420/determine-if-any-type-is-optional/32776488#32776488) the same protocol can be used to provide access to the optional type. Example is in Swift 2, although it should work similarly in previous versions:

```
protocol OptionalProtocol {
    func wrappedType() -> Any.Type
}

extension Optional : OptionalProtocol {
    func wrappedType() -> Any.Type {
        return Wrapped.self
    }
}

let maybeInt: Any = Optional<Int>.Some(12)
let maybeString: Any = Optional<String>.Some("maybe")

if let optional = maybeInt as? OptionalProtocol {
    print(optional.wrappedType()) // Int
    optional.wrappedType() is Int.Type // true
}

if let optional = maybeString as? OptionalProtocol {
    print(optional.wrappedType()) // String
    optional.wrappedType() is String.Type // true
}
```

The protocol can even be used to [check and unwrap the contained optional value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989094/how-to-unwrap-an-optional-value-from-any-type/32780793#32780793)

Answer (score 7):

With Swift2.0:

```
let someString: String? = "oneString"
var anyThing: Any = someString

// is `Optional`
Mirror(reflecting: anyThing).displayStyle == .Optional // -> true
```

But extracting wrapped type is not so easy.

You could:

```
anyThing.dynamicType // -> Optional<String>.Type (as Any.Type)
Mirror(reflecting: anyThing).subjectType // -> Optional<String>.Type (as Any.Type)
```

But I don't know how to extract `String.Type` from `Optional<String>.Type` wrapped with `Any.Type`

Comment: So far its seems like its currently impossible to extract the `String.Type` out of `Optional<String>.self`. However it is possible to extend the `Optional` enum to provide a method that returns the wrapped type, and use any instance to access it.

Comment: Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28964069/3804019)? When you have `Optional<String>.self` as `Optional<String>.Type`, you can. But I thinks it's impossible for  `Any.Type`.

Comment: You just taught me how to do it: if you have `let anyType: Any.Type = Array<String>.self`, then just cast it back: `(anyType as! Array<String>.Type).Element.self` will return `String.Type` :)