# How to get the unwrapped type from an optional type in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm trying to get an unwrapped type from an optional type in runtime.
The following code would print the type of a as `Optional<String>`.

```
class MySubClass: MyClass {

    var a: String? = nil
}

var a = MySubClass()

let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: a)
for child in mirror.children {
    print(child.value.dynamicType)
}
```

Now I want to unwrap the type and get `String`, what should I do to make this happen in runtime?

Comment: To what end? Is it just the log you don't like or you have a real problem?

Comment: In my real case it's like this:     var a: Model? = nil, and I still want the unwrapped type

Comment: Why do you want the unwrapped type would you like to use that? or would you like to write that to the console or somewhere else?

Comment: @GyorgyTrum I want to transfer json into model objects, so I need to know the unwrapped type of every property in an model object.

Comment: @ZhuShengqi: I still don't understand the purpose. You have a JSON but at compile time you don't know which model class should contain that data? So you are calling a web service but you don't know what data it will return?

Comment: @appzYourLife I'm developing a framework, not an app. I can't know the exact json model.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if variable is an Optional, and what type it wraps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32645612/check-if-variable-is-an-optional-and-what-type-it-wraps)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I played with your idea a little bit, but I think there isn't a real way to do that, since you can't get the type of the associated value of an enumeration, yet. Hence Optionals are basically Enumerations, we have a problem here.

My idea would be to test for all possible value types in your model objects could be or hold. Like:

```
let myModelObject:Any? = someWayToGetTheData()
if let aString = myModelObject as? String {
    // do everything you need to store a string
} 
else if let anInteger = myModelObject as? Int {
    // do everything you need to store an integer
} 

// and so on ...
```

Since your json and your model must have a predefined number of supported conversions that is a possible way, and as far as I understand your original problem, it's basically as useful as testing for the dynamic associated value type of an Optional Enumeration, which will lead into a chain of if-else statements as well.

Comment: Yep, ur right. I just find that the reflection API of Swift 2.1 is totally a shit. I have to make every property of model object non-optional, which I think is really an ugly design (optional is a good tool to check if there is a value). Hope Swift 3.0 change this shit.

Comment: @ZhuShengqi: If my answer helps you, it would be great if you could mark it as the the right answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you have an optional

```
let someVar: String?
```

then `print(type(of: someVar))` will print

```
Optional<String>
```

but if you add the following extension to `Optional`

```
protocol OptionalProtocol {
 func wrappedType() -> Any.Type
}

extension Optional: OptionalProtocol {
 func wrappedType() -> Any.Type {
   return Wrapped.self
 }
}
```

then `print(someVar.wrappedType())` will print

```
String
```

No reflection whatsoever

---

**Summary**

As long as the optional is not referenced by `Any` or `AnyObject` the code will work fine.

For `Any` you will have to cast it to `OptionalProtocol` first. Running

```
let someVar: String?
let anyVar = someVar as Any

if let op = anyVar as? OptionalProtocol {
    print(op.wrappedType())
}
```

will print

```
String
```

As for `AnyObject`, strangely enough (at least for me), it doesn't cast to `OptionalProtocol`.

---

The original StackOverflow answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32781143/396949)

Answer (score 0):

You can either unwrap the optional explicitly with a bang (`!`) or with an `if let`.

For example:

```
var foo: String? = nil
if foo == nil {
    print("foo is nil")
    foo = "bar"
}

let fooBang = foo!
print("fooBang: \(fooBang)")

if let ifLetFoo = foo {
    print("ifLetFoo: \(ifLetFoo)")
}
```

This will print:

```
foo is nil
fooBang: bar
ifLetFoo: bar
```

In your context, I think `print(child.value.dynamicType!)` might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't want the value. I want the unwrapped object type, even the target is nil. But thanks anyway : )

Answer (score 0):

If you cast the value to the non-optional String, it will print you the unwrapped type.

```
let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: a)
for child in mirror.children {
    print(String(child.value).dynamicType) //String
}
```

Or you can play with the String and get the type from the Optional type.

```
class MySubClass: MyClass {

var a: Int? = nil
}

var a = MySubClass()

let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: a)
for child in mirror.children {
     let typeArr = String(child.value.dynamicType).characters.split{$0 == "<"}.map(String.init)
     let typeArr2 = typeArr[1].characters.split{$0 == ">"}.map(String.init)

      print(typeArr2[0]) // print: Int
 }
```

Sorry this is lame but you can do something like this.

Comment: I need the type not the name of that type : (